# Print lines from file between header and empty line

Tags: python, file

I have a file with the following structure: header - data - blank lines - header ... I am trying to print the lines of my datafile between the header and the first blank line. The piece of code I am using doesn't seem to work; do you have any suggestion?

```
for j in range(0, number_of_angles, 1):
    start_line = omega_line_number[j]+5 #start line is the line number after the header
    print start_line
    for line in range(start_line,num_lines,1): #num_lines is the total number of lines
        stripped = line.strip()
    if not stripped:
        break
    print line
```

Comment: Please give us some sample data, it will make the question clearer.

Comment: Here's an extract from the data file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2684973/peaks_t20.spt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick program that works on a text file I made for this.  Basically, the text file contains 10 lines containing the word "header" and 20 lines containing the word "body".  After that, I have 10 blank lines and repeat the first 30 lines.  Here is the code that prints only the body.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                       
    # Open the file for reading.                                                 
    rd_file_name = "../txt/q1.txt"                                               
    rd_file = open(rd_file_name, 'r')                                            

    # Read through the header                                                    
    for line in rd_file.readlines():                                             
        # Decide what to do based on the content in the line.                    
        if "header" in line.lower():                                             
            # Don't print the header                                             
            pass                                                                 
        elif line.strip() == "":                                                 
            # Quit if you see a blank line                                       
            break                                                                
        else:                                                                    
            # We print the body.  Lines end with a carriage return, so we don't  
            # add another one.                                                   
            print line,                                                          

    # Clean up                                                                   
    rd_file.close()
```

Comment: How could I repeat this for each of the header + data blocks I have?

Comment: The easiest way is to not break with the empty line.  Just pass like you do for the header.  That would print every "body" in the file.

Comment: OK. Is there a way to derive, for each block, what number it is so to mark the corresponding lines?

Comment: You would have to put a counter in the "if header..." statement along with a safety to make sure that you don't over count the blocks.  If the safety is on, don't increase the counter.  When you increase the counter, turn the safety on.  When you get a blank line, turn the safety off.

Answer (score 0):

`line` is going to be an `integer`, and doesn't have a method, `strip()`

Comment: My idea was to print the lines between "start_line" and the first blank line. I am doing something wrong?